# How to perform a group by with aggregation on a collection in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I want to group the "Incident Types" in the PowerApps collection shown below and sum the first column which is the "Incident Count". I have attempted to use the Group By function, but I was unable achieve the desired result. I simply want the total "Incident Count" for all "Incident Types".

Thanks

[image: Collection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a grouping I have here with a count column:

```
ClearCollect(colGroupsRelation, 
    SortByColumns(
        AddColumns(
            GroupBy(colAppServersRelationAll, "ServerID","ServerGroup"),
            "AppCount", 
            CountRows(ServerGroup)
        ),
    "AppCount", Descending)
);
```

To Explain:

- GroupBy(**MyCollection**, "**Grouping On**", "**Name of the group**")
- AddColumns(**MyCollection** - *'note how I'm using the GroupBy'*, **"Column Name"**, **"Expression"**)
- SortByColumns(**MyCollection**, **"Column To Sort"**, **"Direction to sort"**),

You case might be like

```
AddColumns(
    GroupBy(YourDataSource, "Incident Types","IncidentTypesGroup"),
    "IncidentCountTotal", 
    Sum(IncidentTypesGroup,IncidentCount)
)
```